# numpy.searchsorted for multiple instances of the same entry - python

Tags: python, numpy, search

I have the following variables:

import numpy as np

```
gens = np.array([2, 1, 2, 1, 0, 1, 2, 1, 2])
p = [0,1]
```

I want to return the entries of `gens` that match each element of `p`.

So ideally I would like it to return:

```
result = [[4],[2,3,5,7],[0,2,6,8]] 
#[[where matched 0], [where matched 1], [the rest]]
```

--

My attempts so far only work with one variable:

```
indx = gens.argsort()
res = np.searchsorted(gens[indx], [0])
gens[res] #gives 4, which is the position of 0
```

But I try with with

```
indx = gens.argsort()
res = np.searchsorted(gens[indx], [1])
gens[res] #gives 1, which is the position of the first 1.
```

So:

- how can I search for an entry that has multiple occurrences
- how can I search for *multiple* entries each of which have multiple occurrences?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can use [np.where](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.13.0/reference/generated/numpy.where.html)

```
>>> np.where(gens == p[0])[0]
array([4])

>>> np.where(gens == p[1])[0]
array([1, 3, 5, 7])

>>> np.where((gens != p[0]) & (gens != p[1]))[0]
array([0, 2, 6, 8])
```

Or [np.in1d](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.in1d.html) and [np.nonzero](https://docs.scipy.org/doc/numpy-1.15.0/reference/generated/numpy.nonzero.html)

```
>>> np.nonzero(np.in1d(gens, p[0]))[0]

>>> np.nonzero(np.in1d(gens, p[1]))[0]

>>> np.nonzero(~np.in1d(gens, p))[0]
```